# changing the role of the underline and the minus-sign just in LateX-mode

Tags: key-bindings, auctex

During the work with tex files with auctex+emacs (LateX-mode), I use more frequently _ (underline) instead of - (minus sign).
The same as ^ instead of 6.
The inconvenience is that I should press more frequently the shift-key.

It would be desirable to customize emacs in such a way that when emacs is in LateX-mode (**and just in this mode**), when I type - the the emacs types _ and when I type _ the emacs types -.
i.e., the following key-bindings:

- gives _

_ gives -

6 gives ^

^ gives 6

Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-latex-hook)

(defun my-latex-hook ()
  (require 'tex-site)
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "-" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "_")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "_" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "-")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "6" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "^")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "^" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "6"))))
```

Comment: wonderful, your code perfectly works.

Comment: `(define-key LaTeX-mode-map "-" "_")` and so on should be sufficient (`"_"` is interpreted as a keyboard macro), plus this works with `TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript`.

Comment: Nope, @Constantine. What you suggest will cause recursion.

Comment: Oh, right. It does if `_` and `-` are mapped to each other.