# Inserting electric braces in AUCTeX

Tags: latex, auctex

This is a question a friend of mine had; figured posting here might give quick responses.

> **Old version in new language, après `Name`**
>
> How do I define the mapping `^` |--> `^` while `^^` |--> `^{}`. Similarly, for `_`.
>
> **Old Version**
>
> Is there a way to modify the electric braces for superscript and subscript to behave as follows:
>
> - Insert no empty pair of braces when a carat `^` or underscore `_` is entered.
> - Insert a empty pair of braces when a carat `^` (resp. underscore `_`) is entered following a `^` carat (resp. `_` underscore) sign.

Any answer would be helpful.

/p/s/ The motivation is to minimise having to jump out of braces when the subscript or superscript is just really a character long.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Do you mean the mapping `^-->nothing` and `^^-->{}` or `^-->^` and `^^-->^{}` ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like to have. Thanks.

Comment: Just a clarification. Do you mean `^-->^`?

Comment: Yup, otherwise, that was me being silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you asked for. It also put the cursor between the braces.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-latex-hook)

(defun my-latex-hook ()
  (require 'tex-site)
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "^" 
    (lambda () 
      (interactive) 
      (if (equal (preceding-char) ?^) 
          (progn (insert "{}")(backward-char)) 
        (insert "^")))))
```

The credit is due to @abo-abo for his/her answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3882/2609 from which I got this idea.