# Debugging "Warning: Reference to free variable"

Tags: variables, byte-compilation, warning

I have something like below (from the [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3882/)) in my init file:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-latex-hook)

(defun my-latex-hook ()
  (require 'tex-site)
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "-" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "_")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "_" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "-")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "6" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "^")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "^" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "6"))))
```

When I byte-compile the init file, there is a message: `Warning: reference to free variable LaTeX-mode-map`.  The function works without problem in LaTeX-mode. Should one take this message serious? Is there a better way to write the above function in order to prevent this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is safe, because when your hook is executed LaTeX is
already loaded and `LaTeX-mode-map` is defined. Byte compiler cannot know
that because when it compiles your file LaTeX mode is not loaded and thus
symbol `LaTeX-mode-map` considered free variable.

Apart from the technique you use, you can use `eval-after-load`:

```
(eval-after-load 'my-file
  ;; use functions from ‘my-file’ without fear
  )
```

If you don't want to see the warning you can load file that contains
`LaTeX-mode-map` only when you byte-compile your file:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'my-file))
```

This will not slow down Emacs on startup since `my-file` will be loaded only
when your file is going to be compiled.

Many people will argue that you shouldn't compile your configuration files,
though.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going for a single file init, you can add this declare:

```
(defvar LaTeX-mode-map)
```

If you have multiple files, like I do, just require `tex-site` at top level, see [ora-latex.el](https://github.com/abo-abo/oremacs/blob/github/oleh/modes/ora-latex.el).  What I do is load this always:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-latex-hook)
```

But then `my-latex-hook` is an autoloaded function in `ora-latex.el`. So the whole file isn't loaded until necessary.  The `my-latex-hook` function is usually empty, unless I need to enable some minor modes or set mode-local vars. The `define-key` statements are run only once instead of each time a new tex file is opened, which isn't a big deal but it's nice to have.