# How to "swap" only the numerical row of a keyboard inside Emacs?

Tags: key-bindings, input-method, customization, keyboard

My question is:

when I am editing (La)TeX code, regularly I need to type the famous dollar signs in order to put mathematical code (`$x^2+y^2=z^2$`), a very frequent thing indeed.

**Therefore**, I would like to change the keyboard input inside Emacs (preferably only in TeX-related modes), in order to swap the numerical row of the keyboard; that way, I don't need to press Shift key in order to insert special symbols in the numerical row like `$&*#%`[]...

(Also, my keyboard is a [Brazilian ABNT2](http://s2.glbimg.com/hlQMZ_E87B3DB_96rVuO_pY2Yy8=/695x0/s.glbimg.com/po/tt2/f/original/2016/06/21/900px-kb_portuguese_brazilsvg_.png))

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to a Brezilian keyboard. For swapping an ordinary US Qwerty keyboard you can use the following. You can adapt it for any keyboard. (This is essentially the answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3882/ duo to @abo-abo).

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-latex-hook)
(defun my-latex-hook ()
  (require 'tex-site)
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "`" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "~")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "~" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "`")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "1" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "!")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "!" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "1")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "2" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "@")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "@" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "2")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "3" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "#")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "#" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "3")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "4" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "$")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "$" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "4")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "5" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "%")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "%" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "5")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "6" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "^")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "^" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "6")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "7" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "&")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "&" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "7")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "8" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "*")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "*" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "8")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "9" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "(")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "(" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "9")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "0" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert ")")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map ")" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "0")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "-" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "_")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "_" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "-")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "+" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "=")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map "=" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "+")))
)
```